# how to run any program when connecting any device through ActivSync

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

how to run any program when connecting any device through ActivSync ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [RAPI2 api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920150.aspx), you can write code on the desktop to detect the device activesync connection and then use CeCreateProcess to start a process on the remote device.

Answer (score 0):

Use registry based notification events, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861759.aspx)

> Registry-based notification is based on two predefined events, AutoStartOnConnect and AutoStartOnDisconnect, each of which has its own registry key. When either event occurs, a command associated with the corresponding key is executed.
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect
>
> To associate an application with an event
>
> 1. Construct a value that uniquely identifies the application. The value should include a company and product name — MicrosoftActiveSync, for example.
> 2. Enter the identifier value under one or both AutoStartOn registry keys.
> 3. The data for the identifier should be the command line for the application to be executed, including arguments. The command line must be enclosed in quotation marks if arguments are used.
>
> The following registry editor (.reg) file shows how to register a command line for both AutoStartOnConnect and AutoStartOnDisconnect. When the Windows CE-based device is connected, Notepad is started with a command-line argument of C:\Config.sys. When the Windows CE-based device is disconnected, Notepad is started with a command-line argument of C:\Autoexec.bat.

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect]
    "MicrosoftActiveSync"="\"notepad"\ c:\\config.sys"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect]
    "MicrosoftActiveSync"="\"notepad"\ c:\\autoexec.bat"
```